# Button action method not firing

Tags: ios

```
(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {  
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        // keyboard view found; add the custom button to it
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }

    }
}

- (void)doneButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Input: %@", textField.text);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

The action method is working fine. But when tested in iOS 8.3 beta 4 version the action method is not calling..????

Comment: Thanks for editing Marcus..Can you please answer why the doneButton method is not firing in iOS 8.3 beta 4

Comment: You should not be messing with the keyboard. That's not supported. Never has been. Use an inputAccessoryView for the text field or text view. That's what it is for.

Comment: Thanks ready:- Is it possible to put a button over an IOSNumerickeyboard, just on top on any digit using inputAccessoryView..Any sample code will be helpful.

Comment: The inputAccessoryView goes above the keyboard. If you want a custom keyboard, create a custom keyboard.

Comment: if we put accessory view over iOS native keyboard, the action method is not calling when user taps